# Thunderbird mails from Outlook linked account treated as spam

Tags: thunderbird

I have linked two accounts in Thunderbird, one Gmail and one Outlook.

When I sent a mail from the Outlook one the mail in the recipient go straight into the Spam folder. After sending a mail directly from Outlook.com it is not treated as spam.

In the Gmail account I have no such problem.